# Connecting Polar Graph Coordinates

Tags: java, polar-coordinates

My program is a Polar graphing window. My issue is that when I graph `r=a*sin(b*theta)`. My specific example shown below uses `a=12` and `b=8`. When I connect the point drawn to the next I get something show below:

[image: Polar Graph]

The lines seem to be drawn across the petals, which looks wonderful, but is not correct. Below is the code drawing the points and lines:

```
for(int i=0; i< ptr.size(); i++){
        drawPoint(g2d, ptr.get(i), ptt.get(i));
        if(connectPoints && i!=ptr.size()-1){
            g.drawLine((int)(origin_x+Math.cos(ptt.get(i))*ptr.get(i)*ppp), 
                    (int)(origin_y-Math.sin(ptt.get(i))*ptr.get(i)*ppp), 
                    (int)(origin_x+Math.cos(ptt.get(i+1))*ptr.get(i+1)*ppp), 
                    (int)(origin_y-Math.sin(ptt.get(i+1))*ptr.get(i+1)*ppp));
        }
}
```

`ptr` contains the r values and `ptt` contains the theta values. Here is the line adding the points:

```
for(double i=0; i<100; i+=0.1){
        pg.plot(12*Math.cos(8*i), i);
}
```

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're traversing the circle more than once and your sample points are not the same on each pass. That is why you are getting lines cutting across the petals. Try:

```
double numberOfSteps = 1000;
double stepSize = 2.0 * Math.PI / numberOfSteps; 
for(double i=0; i<numberOfSteps; i++){
    double theta = i * stepsize;
    pg.plot(12*Math.cos(8.0 * theta), theta);
}
```

Experiment with `numberOfSteps` to fine tune.

Comment: Thanks that worked for this example. Although plotting the points is done in a test class for the polar graphing window. Is there a way to fix this without knowing the number of steps and only having a List of points?

Comment: @Dando18 The quick answer is _yes_. Implementing it depends on what part of the code you can change. My initial idea was to create a class `PolarCoordinate` that holds both `r` and `theta`. You should probably ensure that `0 <= theta < 2* Math.PI`. Put these in the list and sort the list by `theta`. Then you can plot them.

Comment: I solved it by adding `theta %= 2*Math.PI` before I add the point to the List, your answer led me to this however so thanks!